# AutoMapper issue with Entity Framework database query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have following simple query:

```
IQueryable<Corporate>  corporates = dbEntities.Corporates.Where(c => c.CorporateName.ToLower().Contains(corporateInfo.SearchCriteria.ToLower()))
                                        .OrderByDescending(u => u.Id);
```

After this I am 'automapping' my EF object into my POCO class, as below:

```
List<CorporateInfoDTO> corporateList = Mapper.Map<List<Corporate>, List<CorporateInfoDTO>>(corporates.ToList());
```

My structure of `CorporateInfoDTO` is as below, for simplicity I have removed unnecessary properties:

```
public class CorporateInfoDTO 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string CorporateName { get; set; }

    public PrimaryContactDTO ContactPerson { get; set; }
}

public class PrimaryContactDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //and so on
}
```

And my mapping configuration:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Corporate, CorporateInfoDTO>()
          .ForMember(dest => dest.ContactPerson, 
                     opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ContactPerson));
```

Now my question is, I AM able to do 'automapping' correctly but I can see individual queries of `ContactPerson` being fired for each row of `Corporate` table in SQL profiler. How to fix this without writing 'select' in EF query?

Also I am wondering how automapper is able to fire a query after `.ToList()` has been called? Or may be my mistake in understanding?

Comment: Have you tried using `ProjectTo<>` instead of `Map<>`? See [AutoMapper.EF6](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.EF6). More on this in here https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions

Comment: @AndrésRobinet nope, let me try this

Comment: AM cannot "fire query" after `ToList`. What you see is a result of EF lazy loading feature. To fix it, use eager loading (e.g. `corporates.Include(c => c.ContactPerson)`).